# Translate all vertices of all selected objects

Tags: transforms

I have a lot of objects. I need to translate every vertex of every object by an offset, without moving the objects origin. For a single object, I can do this <kbd>Tab</kbd>bing into *Edit Mode*, selecting all with <kbd>A</kbd>, and then translating with <kbd>G</kbd>. I would have to repeat this for every object.

If I select every object in *Object Mode*, I can translate everything with <kbd>G</kbd>, but the transform is not applied to just vertices; it moves the origin, too. I need this to export the mesh with Ogre exporter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After placing the objects you can `Apply Transform`:

Object -> Apply -> Location.

Note that the Exporter should handle this and you could report a bug to the author.

*So far the answers here have focused on how to do this from Python, but Im not sure why that is, the question isn't asking about scripting and there is a tool handle this.*

Comment: why focus on a python solution? maybe to provide general solutions that could apply in more scenarios than just the question description. The title might attract different use cases.

Comment: @zeffi, I don't think we should be giving answers that involve knowing Python unless its not possible from the default tool-set.

Comment: This is really what I was looking for! Just so simple...

Answer (score 5):

This might not be the best solution, but being a developer I can't resist myself from posting this answer... :-)

Open console and type following:

```
# Move mesh vertices without affecting its origin
def move_by_amount(x, y, z, only_selected=True): # Default is True
    if only_selected:
        meshes = (obj.data for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects if obj.type == 'MESH')
    else:
        meshes = bpy.data.meshes
    for mesh in meshes: # We move selected/all meshes
        for vertex in mesh.vertices:
            vertex.co += Vector((x, y, z)) # See comments

# Replace with your own x, y, z coordinates
move_by_amount(10, -15, 5, True) # True to move only selected objects
move_by_amount(10, -15, 5, False) # False to move all objects
move_by_amount(10, -15, 5) # Default is True to move only selected objects
```

This has at least passed a basic test with few cubes without changing origins. Please test with your data. You can always undo if things go wrong! ;-)

Comment: Even if zeffii's solution works, this *function* solution is more elegant.

Comment: @zeffii yes.. I've already written that in comment. But we can add one more simple for loop in exchange of simplicity... :-)

Comment: Suggest to += a Vector() rather then x,y,z - which will be slower because of multiple attribute access and internal update functions.

Comment: Also note, typically you wont want to access all meshes in a blend file, so useful for an example but if you write a tool, use visible/selected objects from the context.

Comment: @ideasman42 Thanks for feedback. Just compared with Vector() solution with timeit, but the *total difference* is not more than 0.02 sec (for mesh having over 100K vertices, so about .2 microsec per vertex). And I say *difference* because in some (few) cases this solution is faster (by negligible amount). So I'll keep it as it is and add a comment regarding this.

Comment: I also talked with my friend who's an *artist*, and I learnt about Blender artists terminology of dealing with *selected* objects. So I'll update answer to consider only selected objects (and fill the developer-artist gap :P)

Comment: Well... updated for community demands :/

Answer (score 4):

Heres a solution that avoids accessing verts one at a time.

Theres also the `gotcha` that an object may share mesh data, so you wont want to transform these more then once (thats why its using a `set`).

```
import bpy

def move_by_amount(x, y, z):
    from mathutils import Matrix
    matrix = Matrix.Translation((x, y, z))
    mesh_unique = set(obj.data for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects)
    for mesh in mesh_unique:
        mesh.transform(matrix)
        mesh.update()

# Replace with your own x, y, z coordinates
move_by_amount(10, -15, 5)
```

Comment: I like this one way more than my solution, which i will delete now. Definitely good to encourage the use of Matrix :)

Comment: Well... this applies to me too... I recommend OP to select this instead of mine :) I learnt about [`Mesh.transform`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.transform).